# Find single unique value in list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of key-value pairs in tuples, and it's known that one (and only one) of those tuples will contain a different value.  The keys are all different.  For example,

```
pairs = [
         ('John', 101991),
         ('Bob', 101991),
         ('Tom', 101997),
         ('Larry', 101991),
         ('Howard', 101991)
         ]
```

I need to identify the key of the tuple with the different value.  It is not known whether this value will be larger or smaller than the others.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
pairs = [
     ('John', 101991),
     ('Bob', 101991),
     ('Tom', 101997),
     ('Larry', 101991),
     ('Howard', 101991)
     ]
new_pairs = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(pairs, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]
new_val = [a for a, b in new_pairs if len(b) == 1]
```

Output:

```
[101997]
```

Edit: more efficient solution using dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in pairs:
   d[b].append(a)

new_val = [a for a, b in d.items() if len(b) == 1]
```

Comment: This is O(nlogN); using a dictionary you can make this O(N). For large inputs this matters.

Comment: Why store the names at all? You want to count, not list them. `d = Counter(b or a, b in new_pairs)`, then `[b for b, count in d.items() if count == 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

or alternatively

```
pairs = [
         ('John', 101991),
         ('Bob', 101991),
         ('Tom', 101997),
         ('Larry', 101991),
         ('Howard', 101991)
]

stat = {}
for k, v in pairs:
    if not v in stat: stat[v] = []
    stat[v].append((k, v))

for v in stat:
    if len(stat[v]) == 1:
        print(stat[v][0][0]) #prints the key 'Tom'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd pick out just a list of the keys and a list of the values separately by unzipping:

```
keys, vals = zip(*pairs)
```

Then I'd count the number of each unique value with numpy:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(vals, return_counts=True)
```

And the value you want is the one with the smallest counts:

```
myminval = unique[np.argmin(counts)]
```

Then you find this value in your list of keys:

```
keys[vals.index(myminval)]
```